# Page speed - any problems with simply using defer attribute?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dynamic-script-loading, deferred-loading

Google recommends scripts should be "deferred", but they do not mention the `defer` attribute of the `<script>` tag. I wonder why they don't even mention it, considering it has been around a while.

Instead they suggest injecting scripts into the DOM. Is there any particular benefit of this over using the much simpler and cleaner `defer` attribute?

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload?csw=1#DeferLoadingJS

I gather there are some minor issues with old browsers but I am not supporting anything before IE10 and mostly interested in optimising for mobile browsers.

**UPDATE:**
As an interesting note it turns out you can't use any script loading technique if you are using google maps API. The maps API uses `document.write` to load other scripts, so it cannot be used in a deferred or async script and it cannot be injected into the DOM either, because the `document.write` will not fire. It would be nice if Google followed their own recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent a script from blocking during load by using the `async` attribute on modern browsers:

```
<script async
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=apiloaded">
</script>
```

The `defer` attribute indicates not to load at all until the page DOM has completely loaded. Defer implies async.

For older browser support, the page speed code you linked is correct.

With the Google Maps API, you must use a callback parameter when loading the API asynchronously. This causes the api to use dynamic script insertion rather than `document.write` calls internally. You can specify an empty callback parameter as well.

### A note on Page Speed

Page speed is an excellent tool to help optimize a web site. I listed the `async` attribute because it allows the maps api to be downloaded in parallel (non-blocking). Page speed recommendations may show the most common way to decrease load times, but they are definitely not the only way.

[Optimizing map load times](http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2010/05/12/google-maps-api-v3-developing-for-mobile-devices/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer on the google maps part of my question. I will check that out! I was referring to the defer attribute rather than the async attribute, so that answers only half my question. Sorry for making it a two part question! (Not sure whether to accept the answer now or not!;)

Comment: I added `defer` vs. `asynch` information to the answer. Most uses make `async` more valuable, but there are rare cases for `defer` as well.

Comment: `defer` scripts execute in order, **not** asynchronously.