# To access Google maps api, when do I need to use the below scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, maps

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

> and

```
<script async defer  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">   </script>
```

> n the above scripts, the difference is API key. I have noticed code samples working with and without API KEY. It says Google Maps Javascript API 2 requires API key and Google Maps Javascript API 3 doesn't require the key. But in the scripts we are not mentioning which version of API it should access. So what makes the difference?

Comment: Both of those scripts are including the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions) (v2 is deprecated and was turned off a long time ago, replaced with a wrapper for v3, it should not be used for new code).

Comment: You mean the  first script shouldn't be used for new code ( eg. Google code samples) ?

Comment: The first one should be fine. If you use the second one, you should *probably* get rid of `async defer` and `&callback=initMap`

Comment: Both of the scripts posted load v3, and are OK for new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script loads the [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions) of the Google Maps Javascript API without an API key:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

This script loads the experimental version of the Google Maps Javascript API asynchronously with an API key:

```
<script async defer  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">   </script>
```

- The API key allows tracking of usage and allows you to purchase additional quota if you need it.

For `async defer` and the `callback` parameter, from the answer to this question: [Page speed - any problems with simply using defer attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016788/page-speed-any-problems-with-simply-using-defer-attribute)

> **async**: You can prevent a script from blocking during load by using the async attribute on modern browsers
>
> **defer**: The defer attribute indicates not to load at all until the page DOM has completely loaded. Defer implies async.
>
> With the Google Maps API, you must use a callback parameter when loading the API asynchronously. This causes the api to use dynamic script insertion rather than document.write calls internally. You can specify an empty callback parameter as well.